# A two-variable Fourier series and a strange integral

Tags: fourier-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I have recently had occasion to investigate the Fourier series of the function $f(x,y)=\log({2+\cos 2\pi x} +\cos{2\pi y})$.  Accordingly, define

$I(m,n)=\int_{0,0}^{1,1}f(x,y)\cos{2\pi mx}\cos{2\pi ny}dxdy$

which is the $(m,n)$th Fourier coefficient.  If there is some easy change of variables or flick of the wrist to compute $I$ in closed terms, I haven't been able to find it. One may compute $I(0,0)=\frac{4G}{\pi}-\log 2$, where $G$ is Catalan's constant.  As for other values, Mathematica's integration routine returns the values $I(1,1)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{\pi}$ and $I(2,1)=1-\frac{10}{3\pi}$ (and takes about 10 minutes per computation).  I have tried and failed to affirm the following conjecture, which seems reasonable to present here.

**Conjecture**. If $(m,n)\neq(0,0)$, then $I(m,n)=a+\pi^{-1}b$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Of course, if you could prove this, it would be great to give a closed formula for $a,b$.

Full disclosure: My interest in this stems from a formula of Kasteleyn for the partition function of dimer coverings of squares; in fact the evaluation of $I(0,0)$ given above can be extracted from his original paper.

Comment: Did you try computing I(1,1) numerically? I am doing this and getting something like -0.14. Did I make a slip? Aah! Conjecture: you wrote "I(1,1)=1/2+2/pi" but mean 1/2-2/pi. Am I right?

Comment: Kevin, Mathematica really did give $1/2+2/Pi$ for I(1,1).  The integrand has a nasty singularity at (1/2,1/2) - what routine are you using to integrate?

Comment: Mathematica is wrong, and Kevin is right.

Comment: @David: "what routine are you using to integrate?" I used pari-gp, and I also simply summed the integrand over 1,000,000 points in the region of integration and divided by 1,000,000 for a check. 


Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is a proof of the conjecture, a proof that also shows how to compute the integrals explicitly.

The proof is somewhat similar to David Speyer's approach, but instead of using multivariable residues, I will just shift a one-variable contour.  Without loss of generality, $m>0$.  Eliminating the trigonometric functions yields $I(m,n)=(-1/4\pi^2) J(m,n)$, where
$$ J(m,n) := \int_{|w|=1} \int_{|z|=1} \log(4+z+z^{-1}+w+w^{-1}) \, z^{m-1} w^{n-1} \, dz \, dw.$$
For fixed $w \ne -1$ on the unit circle, the values of $z$ such that $4+z+z^{-1}+w+w^{-1}$ are a negative real number and its inverse; let $g(w)$ be the value in $(-1,0)$.  The function $\log(4+z+z^{-1}+w+w^{-1})$ of $z$ extends to the complement of the closed interval $[g(w),0]$ in a disk $|z|<1+\epsilon$.  Shrink the contour $|z|=1$ like a rubber band so that it hugs the closed interval.  The upper and lower parts nearly cancel, leaving
$$ J(m,n) = \int_{|w|=1} \int_{z=0}^{g(w)} -2\pi i \, z^{m-1} w^{n-1} \,dz \,dw,$$
with the $-2\pi i$ coming from the discrepancy in the values of $\log$ on either side of the closed interval.  Thus
$$ J(m,n) = -\frac{2 \pi i}{m} \int_{|w|=1} g(w)^m w^{n-1} \, dw.$$
Next use the rational parametrization $(g(w),w) = \left( (1-u)/(u+u^2), (u^2-u)/(1+u) \right)$ that David Speyer wrote out.  There is a path $\gamma$ from $-i$ to $i$ in the right half of the $u$-plane that maps to $|w|=1$ (counterclockwise from $-1$ to itself) and gives the correct $g(w)$.  Integrating the resulting rational function of $u$ gives
$$ J(m,n) = -\frac{2 \pi i}{m} \left.(f(u) + r \log u + s \log(1+u))\right|_\gamma = -\frac{2 \pi i}{m} (f(i)-f(-i) + r \pi i + s \pi i/2),$$
for some $f \in \mathbf{Q}(u)$ and $r,s \in \mathbf{Q}$.  This shows that $I(m,n)=a + b/\pi$ for some $a,b \in \mathbf{Q}$.

**Examples:** *Mathematica* got the answers wrong, presumably because it doesn't understand homotopy very well!  Here are some actual values, computed using the approach above:
$$I(1,1) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{2}{\pi}$$
$$I(2,1) = -1 + \frac{10}{3\pi}$$
$$I(20,10) = -\frac{14826977006}{5} + \frac{56979906453888224582}{6116306625 \pi}.$$

Answer (score 13):

I know how I want to answer this question. I'll write up the easy parts here, and leave the hard part for you :).

---

First some minor changes. It will be convenient to clear out denominators and work with $\log \left( 4 + e^{2 \pi i x} + e^{- 2 \pi i  x} + e^{2 \pi i y} + e^{- 2 \pi i  y} \right)$. That just changes the constant term of your Fourier series by $\log 2$. Next, it is convenient to focus on
$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \log \left( 4 + e^{2 \pi i x} + e^{- 2 \pi i  x} + e^{2 \pi i y} + e^{- 2 \pi i  y} \right) e^{2 \pi i m x} e^{2 \pi i n y} dx dy.$$
A simple linear transformation goes between this and the cosine formulation. Let $S = \{ (z,w) : |z|=|w|=1 \}$. So we are dealing with
$$\frac{1}{(2 \pi i )^2} \int_S \log \left( 4+z+z^{-1} + w +w^{-1} \right) z^{m-1} w^{n-1} dz dw.$$
Dropping out the $4 \pi ^2$, we want to show the integrand is of the form $a \pi + b$.

**UPDATE:** Thanks to fedja for pointing out that I had oversimplified the next paragraph.

Assuming that $(m,n) \neq (0,0)$, we can integrate by parts with respect to one of the two variables, let's say $z$. Once we do that, we will have a quantity of the form
$$ (\mbox{rational number}) \cdot \int_S \frac{(z-z^{-1}) w^k z^{\ell} dw dz} {4+w+w^{-1}+z+z^{-1}}$$

So we'd like to show this quantity is of the form $a+b \pi$.

As fedja points out, we need to be careful here. Without the $z-z^{-1}$ term, the integral diverges like $\int \int ds dt/(s^2 + t^2)$ near $(-1,-1)$.

---

Whew! Now comes the actual hard part. Let 
$$E:=\{ (z,w) \in (\mathbb{C}^*)^2 : \ 4+z+z^{-1}+w+w^{-1} =0 \}.$$
<strike>This is an elliptic curve with four punctures.</strike> As Bjorn points out, this is a nodal cubic and can be parameterized as 
$$(z,w) = \left( \frac{1-u}{u(1+u)}, \frac{u(u-1)}{1+u} \right).$$ 
We'll come back to this point later.

The $2$-form $dw dz/(4+z+z^{-1}+w+w^{-1})$ has a simple pole on $E$. Let $\omega$ be the $1$-form on $E$ which is the residue of that $2$-form.

I think there should be a curve $\gamma$ in $E$ such that $S$ is homotopic, in $(\mathbb{C}^*)^2 \setminus E$, to a tubular neighborhood of $\gamma$. So
$$\int_S \frac{w^k z^{\ell} (z-z^{-1}) dw dz}
{4+w+w^{-1}+z+z^{-1}} = \int_{\gamma} \omega w^k z^{\ell} (z - z^{-1}) .$$

If we substitute in the above parameterization, this will be the integral around a closed loop of some rational function in $\mathbb{Q}(u)$. In particular, we can compute this integral by residues and we will get something of the form $a+b \pi$, as desired.

Actually, it looks to me like we should just get $b \pi$. Maybe the integration by parts doesn't go as well as I hoped?

---

Obviously, someone should actually work this out explicitly, but I don't think it will be me.

Comment: Well, your integration by parts already seems very suspicious: the final integral you wrote certainly diverges at $(-1,-1)$. Still I like your general idea :).

Comment: Hmmm. You're right that integral z^k w^l/(4+...) diverges at (-1,-1). On the other hand, the particular expressions we get out of integrating by parts look like integral (z-z^{-1}) z^k w^l/(4+...) depending on which variable we integrated on. And that should be convergent. I'll edit to point that out.

Comment: As for justifying the integration by parts, the right way to do it is to cut out a small disc D around (-1,-1). There is then a completely valid integration by parts, which winds up with a left over term where we integrate over \partial D. One then has to show that this term drops out when we shrink D. But I'll leave that for someone else.

Comment: @David: Don't wimp out yet!  Your "elliptic curve" is singular at (-1,-1), so it's just a rational curve, which should make your life much, much easier...

Comment: @David: "Dropping out the 4 pi^2, we want to show the integrand is of the form a pi +b.". Either I'm misunderstanding or that should be a.pi + b.pi^2?

Comment: David Hansen's conjecture was that the original integral was of the form a+b/pi.

Comment: Right. So when you multiply by pi^2 you get a.pi^2+b.pi? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh, wait, you're right and I'm dumb. Now I'm really confused. This is tempting me to actually work out the example in full, but that will take a while. 

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to compute values of I(m,n) numerically to, say, 10 dec places? (or even 5 dec places?). Pari's "lindep" function is good at using LLL to spot when a real number is of the form a+b/Pi with a,b rational, so one could try some examples to see whether the conjecture holds out more generally.

Answer (score 5):

Mathematica gets the (1,1) case right.

Integrate the x-variable to obtain an answer 
that involves the absolute value of Cos[Pi y].

Then split the y-integral at y=1/2 to get the 
correct value.

The answer is 1/2 - 2/Pi