# An elementary number theoretic infinite series

Tags: nt.number-theory, polymath5

For a positive integer $k$, let $d(k)$ be the number of divisors of $k$. So $d(1)=1$, $d(p)=2$ if $p$ is a prime, $d(6)=4$, and $d(12)=6$.

What are the precise asymptotics of $\sum_{k=1}^n 1/(k d(k))$?

### Background:

1) This came up on the side in the [polymath5](http://gowers.wordpress.com/2010/03/13/edp12-representing-diagonal-maps/#comment-6697) project.

2) There, Tim Gowers wrote: If nobody knows the answer, maybe that’s one for MathOverflow, where I imagine a few minutes would be enough.

3) Asked: 14:17 Jerusalem time. (The first accurate answer: 17:44 Jerusalem time.)

4) Looking only at primes or only at integers with a typical number of divisors suggested a $\log\log n$ behavior, but looking at semiprimes indicates the sum is larger. I don't know how much larger.

5) I couldn't find an answer on the web. If there is an easy way searching for an answer that I missed this will be interesting too.

## Follow up:

Great answers! Thanks. What about the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n 1/(kd^2(k))$ ?

Comment: SUM_{k=1}^n 1/kd(k) ... Does that mean $\sum_{k=1}^n 1/(k d(k))$ or $\sum_{k=1}^n d(k)/k$ ?


Comment: The former, according to Gil's link.

Comment: It's a sum of multiplicative functions so should be amenable to using Dirichlet series.

Comment: If I had to guess, since d(k) is log(k) on the average the asymptotics should be like that of sum 1/(k log k).

Comment: The correct guess is C*(log N)^(1/2). Look-up the Selberg-Delange method. (The point is that sum(z^w(n), n <= X) ~ C*(log X)^(z-1) and (1/2)^w(n) is essentially the same as 1/d(n), so by partial summation we get sum(1/kd(k),k <= X) ~ C*(log X)^(1/2-1+1))

Comment: oups... i meant sum(z^w(n), n <= X) ~ C * X * (log X)^{z-1} in my comment above.

Comment: The semiprimes already push the loglogn to (loglogn)^2, I think, so I did not have a definite guess. For the polymath purposes hoped it is a power of logn.

Comment: Re: the followup.  If the hypotheses of the Delange (or Raikov) Tauberian theorem are satisfied, then `$\sum_n 1/(n d(n)^2)$` should be $\sim C (\log x)^{1/4}$, since if $p$ is prime, $d(p) = 2$.

Comment: Along with David Hansen's remark below, this shows that `$\sum_{n \le x} 1/(n d(n)^k) \sim C(k) (log x)^{1/2^k}$` for some nonzero $C(k)$.

Comment: Maks' Hansen's and Miller's answers are excellent. I'd accept all of them if this was possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The idea (from the Selberg-Delange) method to doing this problem is the following steps:

1) Let $F(s) = \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{n^s d(n)} = \prod_{p} \left(1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+1) p^{ks}} \right)$.  The latter is by multiplicativity of $d(n)$.

2) If we look, instead at $G(s) = \prod_p \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2 p^s} \right)$ we can see that $F(s)/G(s)$ has a non-zero limit as $s \rightarrow 1$ from above.  $G(s)$ corresponds in our original sum to restricting $n$ to be square-free.

3) $G(s)^2$ almost looks like $\zeta(s)$.  Show that $G(s)^2/\zeta(s)$ also has a non-zero limit at $s \rightarrow 1$.

4) You then use some Tauberian theorems to show that since $H_n \sim \log n$ (which is the sum associated with $\zeta(s)$ then the corresponding sum for $G(s)$ (i.e. over the square-free $n$) is $\sim to \sqrt{\log n}$.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I believe this idea predates Selberg and Delange by almost half a century. This was done already in 1908 by Landau to find the number of numbers represented by a sum of two squares. But since Selberg-Delange has been mentioned quite a few times in this post, I am doubting myself.

Comment: @Dror: Yes, I was reminded of the Landau result you quoted too.  I think what Delange did was to give a Tauberian theorem that was strong enough to deduce things like the following:

`$F(s) = \sum_n \frac{a_n}{n^s}$`.  and $F(s)^r/\zeta(s)$ has a non-zero limit when $s \rightarrow 1$, for some integer $r$ then
`$sum_{n \le x} a_n \sim C (\log x)^{1/r}$` for some non-zero $C$.  Ramanujan's paper only announces the results.  It doesn't have any proofs.

Comment: The Tauberian theorem you mention was actually proved by Raikov: "Generalisation of a theorem of Ikehara–Landau (in Russian). Mat.
Sbornik, 45 (1938)". If I am not mistaken, the Selberg-Delange method is more about getting a better error term (dating 1947?). Of course the particular instance of Landau was also proved and can be found in:  "Über die Einteilung der positiven ganzen Zahlen in vier Klassen nach der Mindeszahl der zu ihrer additiven Zusammensetzung erforderlichen Quadrate." Arch. Math. Phys. 13, 305-312, 1908.

Comment: Suppose $D(s)$ is a Dirichlet series with multiplicative coefficients.  If $D(s)=\zeta(s)^{a}F(s)$ where $a$ is rational and $F(s)$ is an Euler product which converges without zeros or poles in $\mathrm{Re}(s)> \delta$ for some $\delta < 1$, then you do NOT need a Tauberian theorem to study partial sums of the coefficients of $D(s)$.  It is enough to apply a usual contour integration argument, but instead of shifting the whole contour you deform it around the singularity at $s=1$.  The partial sums end up being $~c(\alpha)X(\log{X})^{a-1}$ where I forget $c(a)$ (it is simple).

Comment: ("\alpha" should be "a")

Comment: @Hansen: That is a, and is the mentioned, Tauberian theorem.

Comment: @David: thanks for that.  But, in some sense your argument is a Tauberian theorem, just with weaker hypotheses and a simpler proof.

Answer (score 11):

The correct asymptotic is $C \cdot (\log N)^{1/2}$. (c.f Selberg-Delange method).

Comment: Nice answer! I wishes I knew more about Selberg Delange method.

Comment: The main contribution to the sum will come from the integers n <= N, with (1/2)loglog N + O((loglog N)^(1/2 + epsilon)) prime factors. This is again a consequence of... the Selberg-Delange method.

Answer (score 10):

(edited)

The answer can be extracted from a paper of Ramanujan, "Some formulae in the analytic theory of numbers", no. 17 in his collected papers.  There he gives, among other things, the formula

$\sum_{n\leq X} \frac{1}{d(n)} \sim \frac{X}{\sqrt{\log{X}}}\pi^{-\frac{1}{2}}\prod_{p}\sqrt{p^2-p}\log{\frac{p}{p-1}}$.

The answer to the original question can be extracted from this by partial summation.

As for the "follow-up", the answer is $\sum_{n \leq X} \frac{1}{n d(n)^2} \sim C (\log{X})^\frac{1}{4}$.  Again, Selberg-Delange...

Comment: That's a nice formula, but Gil asked about the sum of 1/(n d(n)).

Comment: Partial summation.

Comment: Even though it is very elementary, I think you should write the above comment in the actual answer. The way it is currently written is just annoying.

Comment: This is an extremely useful answer. The sum of 1/(d(n)) ; n<= X behaving like x/sqrt (log X) makes it indeed believable that the sum of 1/d(n)n behaves like sqrt log (X). It certainly implies that sum 1/nd(n) it is at least \sqrt (log X).

Comment: Does Ramanujan give a proof or just the formula?

Comment: A remark for those who, like me, were confused: $\sqrt{p^2-p} = p (1-1/(2p)+O(1/p^2))$ and $\log (p/(p-1)) = 1/p + 1/(2 p^2) + O(1/p^3)$ so the factors in the product are $1+O(1/p^2)$ and the product converges.