# Examples of math hoaxes/interesting jokes published on April Fool's day?

Tags: big-list, recreational-mathematics

What are examples of math hoaxes/interesting jokes published on April Fool's day?

For a start [P=NP](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/%7Ezeilberg/mamarim/mamarimPDF/pnp.pdf).

*Added 2024-04-01* Anything new in 2024?

Comment: http://mathforum.org/kb/thread.jspa?threadID=437522 . Also Zeilberger has, of course, many other ones.

Comment: John Baez has been at it overnight: https://plus.google.com/117663015413546257905/posts/EnuZypVRAj5 By contrast with some examples, it is pretty low-key.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PTcJrIz3iKE

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/sci.math/LC71u21hJCE

Comment: @KConrad :-) Did Elkies really participated in this hoax? (this is not clear to me from the thread)

Comment: @joro What is unclear about 'According to Noam, this hoax was "probably" the work of Henri Darmon, and propagated without Noam's knowledge'?

Comment: See also [here](http://www.physicsoverflow.org/35824/p-np-solved-in-the-affirmative) for a simple and almost complete proof of P=NP ... ;-)

Comment: @Dilaton :-) Appears to me the answer completes the proof...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to have run its course.

Comment: @Suvrit Hoaxes last much longer than the single april first.

Comment: RJ Lipton and KW Reagan blogged on April 1:  https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2016/04/01/the-primes-strike-again/

Comment: MO allows questions like this?  Color me surprised.

Comment: @Suvrit keep this open because hoaxes never get stale

Comment: It's been a week and this is still on HNQ.

Comment: @cat what is HNQ?

Comment: @joro Hot Network Questions!

Comment: @cat Whatever the Network is, this explains the large number of visits, thanks. (If it hits something like the old slashdot, SE users will contribute a few millions more hits)

Comment: Joro: Permission for minor edits is implicitly expected on MathOverflow, and is part of the design of the site.  Please do not admonish users for doing so.

Comment: Thanks to those who voted to reopen :-) It will be fun while it lasts.

Comment: My April Fools joke from two days ago was deleted. You need special powers to view it. http://mathoverflow.net/q/266095/16888

Comment: Thank you for the link. https://www.kialo.com/p--np-15955

Answer (score 93):

I enjoyed the hexasphere by
*A. V. Akopyan, J. Crowder, H. Edelsbrunner, R. Guseinov*
from last year:

http://pub.ist.ac.at/~edels/hexasphere/

[image]

In the link, the sphere is animated, so you can look at it from all sides.

Comment: I found a pentagon!

Comment: The JS behind the animation is frustratingly obfuscated. Oh well, another hobby... :D

Comment: 2 July, There are two of them. Try to find the second one!

Comment: I've partially deobfuscated the source here: https://gist.github.com/sleepygarden/1c2496991d9b8534f0cf948bacd22f05

Comment: I tried very hard but couldn't find any pentagon. I'm starting to think the claim that there are pentagons is another april fools joke!

Comment: I found a geodesic digon with one side consisting of 17 hexagons and the other of about 21.

Comment: @Alnitak: If you have a powerful enough imagination you will notice some slight discrepancy between the displayed model and your mental model. (In other words it is a fake rendering, much like http://www.moillusions.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/choc.gif.)

Comment: Is it actually a horosphere?

Answer (score 78):

In 2009, it was discovered that the numerical value of $\pi$ [has changed over time](http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.5321). This is a truly interdisciplinary work connecting the study of ancient cultures with string theory, cosmology and bicycle tires. Let me quote from the introduction:

> Physicists have long speculated that the fundamental
>   constants might not, in fact, be constant, but instead
>   might vary with time. Dirac was the first to suggest this
>   possibility, and time variation of the fundamental constants has been investigated numerous times since then.
>   Among the various possibilities, the fine structure constant and the gravitational constant have received the
>   greatest attention, but work has also been done, for example, on constants related to the weak and strong interactions, the electron-proton mass ratio, and several others.
>
> It is well-known that only time variation of dimensionless fundamental constants has any physical meaning.
>   Here we consider the time variation of a dimensionless
>   constant not previously discussed in the literature: $\pi$. It
>   is impossible to overstate the significance of this constant.
>   Indeed, nearly every paper in astrophysics makes use of
>   it. [..]

Comment: "More speculatively, one might consider the possibility
that the values of the integers could vary with time, a result
suggested by several early Fortran simulations." (p. 2)

Comment: The whole paper is beautiful. No sentence too much. The "leakage" paragraph and Section IV are my favorites.

Comment: It is also conjectured that the constant 1 is subject to infinitesimal quantum fluctuations and assumes at times the value of 0.999... .  Unfortunately no experimental setup allows to observe the phenomenon in its entirety.

Comment: @Florian, this is related to recent observations of particles travelling at speeds higher than the speed of light, related to the upward infinitesimal fluctuations of the constant $1$ assuming the value of $1.000\ldots 1$.

Answer (score 54):

In 1975 Martin Gardner produced a map with 110 regions which he claimed required five colours:

[image: Martin Gardner April Fool '5-colour' map]

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Four-ColorTheorem.html

Comment: At that time I was an Assistant Professor. My mother read the Gardner column in *Scientific American* and sent me a letter asking whether I knew that the Four Color Conjecture had been disproved.

Comment: The puzzle in your answer is different from the one on the page you linked to. So I solved it: http://i.imgur.com/jTbwfnm.png

Comment: @UTF-8 I spotted two touching vertical red pieces on the middle of the RHS.

Comment: Is the punchline that the top half and the bottom half seem to be moving relative to each other in an optical illusion?

Comment: @aetheria: but it's fine: they are not touching, there is a black color in between... oh, wait... that makes it 5 colors  (... or 2 ? if we take this line into account, only 1 other color is required ^^)

Answer (score 45):

Someone (widely believed to be Henri Darmon) circulated the following email on April Fools' Day, 1994:

> There has been a really amazing development today on Fermat's Last Theorem.
> Noam Elkies has announced a counterexample, so that FLT is not true
> after all!  His spoke about this at the Institute today. The solution to
> Fermat that he constructs involves an incredibly large prime exponent
> (larger that 10^20), but it is constructive. The main idea seems to be
> a kind of Heegner point construction, combined with an really ingenious
> descent for passing from the modular curves to the Fermat curve.
> The really difficult part of the argument seems to be to show that the
> field of definition of the solution (which, a priori, is some ring class
> field of an imgainary quadratic field) actually descends to Q.
> I wasn't able to get all the details, which were quite intricate...

> So it seems that the Shimura Taniyama conjecture is not true after
> all. The experts  think that it can still be salvaged, by
> extending the concept of automorphic representation, and introducing a
> notion of ``anomalous curves" that would still give rise to a
> ``quasi-automorphic representation".

The email reached Gian-Carlo Rota at MIT, who took it at face value and circulated it more widely.  Eventually David Feldman posted it to the Usenet group sci.math.  The thread is [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.math/LC71u21hJCE).

Comment: While this was already mentioned by KConrad in a comment, it is good to have it as answer, too.

Comment: @quid (and KConrad):  My apologies.  I'd quite overlooked the comment.

Comment: I like this one because, in my opinion, there is nothing in it which hints at this being a joke. If I saw this by the time FLT wasn't proven yet then I would probably believe it (provided I forgot what day it is :P).

Comment: Worth noting that this was (IIRC) *after* Andrew Wiles had announced his proof, but *before* he fixed the final gap that somebody found while proof-reading it. Bit of a cruel joke really, from Wiles's point of view at least.

Comment: I confess to having been briefly convinced by this one, which a colleague emailed to me.

Answer (score 37):

This one is my favorite (especially **a mixture of anyons and morons with opposite spins**):

```
> From: Enrico Bombieri <eb@IAS.EDU> Tue, 1 Apr 1997 12:35:12 -0500
> Date: Tue, 1 Apr 1997 12:35:12 -0500 To: eb@IAS.EDU,
> zeilberg@euclid.math.temple.edu
> 
> Dear Doron,
> 
> There are fantastic developments to Alain Connes's lecture at IAS last
> Wednesday. Connes gave an account of how to obtain a trace formula
> involving zeroes of L-functions only on the critical line, and the
> hope was that one could obtain also Weil's explicit formula in the
> same context; this would solve the Riemann hypothesis for all
> L-functions at one stroke. Thus there cannot be even a single zeroe(1)
> off the critical line!
> 
> Well, a young physicist at the lecture saw in a flash that one could
> set the whole thing in a combinatorial setting using supersymmetric
> fermionic-bosonic systems (the physics corresponds to a near absolute
> zero ensemble of a mixture of anyons and morons with opposite spins)
> and, using the C-based meta-language MISPAR, after six days of
> uninterrupted work, computed the logdet of the resolvent Laplacian,
> removed the infinities using renormalization, and, lo and behold, he
> got the required positivity of Weil's explicit formula! Wow!
> 
> Regards also from Paula Cohen. Please give this the highest diffusion.
> Best,
> 
> Enrico
> 
> 
> (1) This is the correct spelling, according to vicepresident Dan
> Quayle.
> --------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: "...mixture of anyons, morons, and dorons..." :-)

Answer (score 30):

[only borderline mathematical]

Today Ali Frolop and Douglas Scott published a paper (http://arxiv.org/abs/1603.09703) in which they found:

> ... there is a remarkable correspondence between each type of peculiarity in the digits of π and the anomalies in the CMB.

[image]

Comment: This is not submitted on April first, probably due to timezone issues. Is the paper provably a hoax?

Comment: @joro: here are two proofs. 1. Permute the letters of "Ali Frolop". 2. 
Look here: http://arxiv.org/abs/1504.00108

Comment: @joro 3. proof: April fool is actually mentioned in the text

Comment: http://arxiv.org/find/astro-ph/1/au:+Frolop_A/0/1/0/all/0/1

Comment: @joro And for "not submitted on April first": well, is has to be submitted a bit early to make it into the daily summary e-mails from arxiv

Comment: samcarter: OK, I see it is a _real_ hoax :-)

Answer (score 22):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number#Almost_integers_and_Ramanujan.27s_constant

> This concerns the number $e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}$, and says "In a 1975
>   April Fool article in Scientific American magazine,[7] "Mathematical
>   Games" columnist Martin Gardner made the (hoax) claim that the number
>   was in fact an integer, and that the Indian mathematical genius
>   Srinivasa Ramanujan had predicted it—hence its name."

The punchline is tied into complex multiplication, though I don't know the details.

Comment: This is the second hoax of Gardner here as of now.

Comment: "Mathematical Games" regularly had hoax columns for the April issue.  Gardner then admitted it only in the commentary a month later.

Answer (score 21):

Well, there's the April 1, 1997 paper by Doron Zeilberger, [The Transcendence of E plus Pi and E times Pi](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/mamarim/mamarimhtml/goodwin.html) (the following quote is snipped a bit; full text available at the link).

> The purpose of this note is to announce that Hermite's[H] celebrated
>   result that $e$ is transcendental, combined with an amazing
>   (but apparently overlooked) statement of Goodwin[G], imply
>   the transcendence of both $e + \pi$ and $e \pi$.
>
> But even more interesting than the above implication is the
>   way by which it was arrived, via *computer-generated deduction*.
>
> We first developed a
>   C-based meta-language, MISPAR, that has built-in number-theoretical
>   deduction capabilities, that inputs suitably formatted statements
>   about numbers (especially targeted to handle transcendence theory),
>   and outputs new statements. Then, using 
>   ten diligent graduate students,
>   many results that appeared in papers on the subject were entered
>   in the appropriate format. Then we used a *genetic algorithm* to
>   deduce million of new results, most of them either trivial or
>   uninteresting (or both!).
>
> Then we made a long list of open problems.
>   Whenever the computer made a new deduction, it was compared against
>   the statements in the list, looking for possible matches.
>
> While we sure hoped to obtain new *interesting* 
>   results, even in our wildest
>   dreams we did not anticipate such a spectacular deduction.
>
> We are sure that *MISPAR* would make many more interesting
>   deductions in the future. The package itself, and implementation 
>   details, will be eventually published at the author's website
>   (http://www.math.temple.edu/~zeilberg).
>
> **References**
>
> [G] E. J. Goodwin, *Amer. Math. Monthly*, **1** (1894),
>   246-247.
>
> [H] C. Hermite, *Comptes Rend. Acad. Sci. Paris*, **77** (1873),
>   18-24, 74-79, 285-293.

The explanation is [here](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/mamarim/mamarimhtml/ClearAFJ); apparently, due to some careful phrasing, the statement of the paper is actually technically correct (or at least so says Zeilberger).

Comment: The "careful phrasing" is that Zeilberger claims the result follows from a "statement of Goodwin", but _does not_ claim that said statement of Goodwin is true! E. J. Goodwin is better known as the author of the Indiana Pi Bill, and the title of the unreviewed note in the _Monthly_ cited here is "Quadrature of the Circle". If it was anything like the Pi Bill, I don't think it would take more than one graduate student to derive whatever you'd like from it. (Hooray for explosion).

Answer (score 18):

One year maybe about twenty years ago an April 1 story circulated on email, giving the news that TeX had been sold to Microsoft (and would therefore no longer be free). It included a pretty convincing firsthand account, complete with embarrassing technical glitches when Bill Gates took the stage at the grand public announcement.

Comment: Here's a write-up of the hoax in TUGboat magazine: http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb19-2/tb59hoax.pdf I found this yesterday while reading about a similar hoax on CTAN: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301882/what-is-ctan-org-now

Answer (score 17):

More *Physicsy* than Maths, but there's [Don Schneider's](http://www2.astro.psu.edu/deptinfo/graduate/oldbrochure/faculty/schneider.html) "discovery" of a quasar with redshift **4.1** (NB - the largest quasar red-shift known at that time was 3.7), announced at Institute of Advanced Study, Princeton on 1st April.

The number 4.1 was chosen to be a subtle hint, that this whole presentation was a prank. Few people got it right away, most others didn't and were particularly curious regarding the finer nuances of the discovery, which Schneider did happen to address convincingly on the course of his "report". It was a well-cooked up prank!

This is chronicled in [Ed Regis - ``*Who Got Einstein's Office*'', Addition-Wesley (1987)](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Who_Got_Einstein_s_Office.html?id=j1o4xQhQjDIC&redir_esc=y):

> ... But Schneider hands out his charts to the audience, and there's no 
>   disbelieving the data. Wavelength plotted against energy flux, the graph 
>   looks like a distorted view of lower Manhattan, with sharp peaks and 
>   valleys, and one very sharp spike, looking like the World Trade Center. 
>   That's the quasar, with its record-breaking redshift. 
>   The whole room is abuzz. People are talking to each other a mile a 
>   minute, and John Bahcall has the devil of a time moderating the question 
>   period. They want to know everything: Where's the object located? What's 
>   its coordinates? What's the exact time the observations were taken? But 
>   Don answers them all, every last one. . . until it's clear that the thing has 
>   gone far enough, and he brings it all to a close. There's another speaker to be heard from, poor fellow. Schneider is going to be one tough act to 
>   follow.
>
> Indeed. Some people are even now getting the drift, an inkling of 
>   what's actually been going on here. A redshift of four point one, and today is 
>   April first. Can this be? . . . Oh, Jesus! It must be. And in fact, yes, it is! It's 
>   all . . . an April Fool's joke! Don Schneider has just pulled off the coup of the 
>   decade, getting the combined astrophysical brains of Princeton University, 
>   Bell Labs, and the Institute for Advanced Study to believe that in the space 
>   of a few hours in the morning, at an Institute with absolutely no observing 
>   facilities whatsoever, not even so much as a pair of binoculars, he's discovered the world's farthest object smack in the middle of a gravitational lens.

Answer (score 16):

Paul Taylor, who has often contributed to MO, once posted this to the categories mailing list; the original thread can be found [here](http://www.mta.ca/~cat-dist/archive/1999/99-4):

> From cat-dist Thu Apr  1 10:24:48 1999
>   Received: (from Majordom@localhost)
>     by mailserv.mta.ca (8.9.3/8.9.3) id IAA04316
>     for categories-list; Thu, 1 Apr 1999 08:17:14 -0400 (AST)
>   X-Authentication-Warning: mailserv.mta.ca: Majordom set sender to
>   cat-dist@mta.ca using -f
>   Date: Thu, 1 Apr 1999 13:10:47 +0100 (BST)
>   From: Paul Taylor 
>   Message-Id: <199904011210.NAA21705@wax.dcs.qmw.ac.uk>
>   To: categories@mta.ca
>   Subject: categories: Is Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory inconsistent?
>   Sender: cat-dist@mta.ca
>   Precedence: bulk
>   Status: O
>   X-Status:
>
> ```
>   IS ZERMELO-FRAENKEL SET THEORY INCONSISTENT?
> ```
>
> At the end of this message is a sketch of an argument that leads to
>   the conclusion that Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory is inconsistent.
>
> The impact on mathematics is not as devastating as the incautious
>   observer might suppose.   Recall that ZERMELO set theory (1908), which
>   is essentially equivalent to the categorists' notion of ELEMENTARY TOPOS
>   with natural numbers and the axiom of choice,  is adequate for
>   most of the purposes of mathematics, though not, as I shall try to
>   explain, logic (and theoretical computer science).
>
> ZERMELO-FRAENKEL set theory is the extension of this system by the
>   axiom-scheme of REPLACEMENT, which was first formulated by Adolf
>   (later Abraham) Fraenkel, Nels Lennes and Thoralf Skolem in 1922,
>   although Dimitry Mirimanoff already had something of the idea in 1917.
>   Notice that this is some two decades after the appearance of the famous
>   "antinomies" of set theory, so presumably the set theorists' guard had
>   dropped by that time, and they had begun again to assert megalomaniac
>   axioms.   On the other hand, it is a decade before the second generation
>   of paradoxical results, Godel's incompleteness theorem and Turing's
>   unsolvability of the Halting Problem.
>
> Whenever I see set theory books in a library or bookshop, I turn to
>   the index to find out what they have to say about Replacement.  Usually
>   there is some trivial result, such as the existence of what categorists
>   call image factorisation, that could have been proved from Zermelo's
>   axioms with a little more facility in set-theoretic constructions.
>
> The basic use of Replacement, that you will find in the better set theory
>   books, is the recursive construction of sets (in substance -- types or
>   objects to type-theorists and categorists -- rather than their names).
>
> For example, Mostowski's theorem states that every well founded extensional binary relation < is isomorphic to the membership relation for a unique transitive set.  This is found, recursively, by means of the formula
>       f(x)  =   { f(y) |  y < x },
>   which also provides the extensional reflection (quotient) of any well
>   founded relation. In fact the latter result (where the quotient relation
>   is merely another relation, rather than a membership relation) can be
>   proved using the topos or Zermelo axioms alone, and not Replacement [1],
>   although there are categorical generalisations of this that certainly do
>   need Replacement.
>
> Richard Montague [2] proved a result that should have been taken as a
>   warning of the perilous nature of Replacement, though I suspect that
>   Montague's personal eccentricities may have been the reason why he was
>   ignored. ZF can prove the consistency, not only of Zermelo set theory (Z)
>   itself, but also of Z extended by any single theorem of ZF.
>
> Adrian Mathias has claimed [3] that Bourbaki was "ignorant" of Replacement, ie that it did not occur in "Theorie des Ensembles" [4].   Although Bourbaki is hardly very clear on this matter, it does include a
>   version of Replacement in its axioms, indeed one that is in widespread
>   use in category theory and other parts of mathematics, namely that one
>   can form the UNION of any SET-INDEXED FAMILY of SETS.
>
> One application of N-indexed unions in theoretical computer science is
>   Scott's "D-infinity" construction of models of the untyped lambda calculus.
>   Starting from any domain D0=D, one may form its function-space D1=(D0->D0),
>   and similarly D2=(D1->D1), etc., linking these together with embedding-
>   projection pairs.  If D was one of the examples of L-domains, having a
>   pair of elements with infinitely many minimal upper bounds, then one can
>   show (classically) that D-infinity has the cardinality of a model of
>   Zermelo set theory, so need not exist within such a model unless it also
>   satisfies Replacement.
>
> These two ways of seeing Replacement have a common theme: we use N-indexed or transfinite unions to unfold a free(ish) model of one logic within a model of another.
>
> Having seen this in the context of a messy domain-theoretic construction,
>   we may think in a more disciplined way about free models of the lambda
>   calculus, the topos axioms, etc.  In fact, there is no difficulty in
>   constructing these models, as they are merely TERM ALGEBRAS.  The problem
>   lies in proving that the term algebra has the universal (initiality)
>   property that qualifies it as "free":
>
> Let S be the universe (the category of ZF-sets, for example)
>       and F the term algebra (internal to S) for the logic L.
>       Suppose that S itself is a model of L.
>
> Then there is a unique interpretation functor []:F->S
>       that takes each syntactic operation of F (eg prod(a,b))
>       to the semantics ([a] x [b]) in S.
>
> It is merely unique up to unique isomorphism if the L-structure in S is
>   defined by universal properties rather than being chosen.
>
> This initiality property may also be expressed type-theoretically.
>   Per Martin-Lof [5] introduced objects with such a property, called UNIVERSES, observing the analogy with Replacement.  This point of view stresses that the above property is a RECURSION SCHEME.
>
> Let me explain how I came to realise that the existence of []:F->S depends, in general, on Replacement.
>
> There is an amazingly simple but incredibly powerful argument, due to
>   Peter Freyd and known variously as (Artin-Wraith) glu(e)ing, sconing,
>   the Freyd cover, logical relations and other names.  It is based on some
>   very elementary categorical investigations of a certain comma category 
>   involving F and S.   This argument has been developed rather a long way
>   (the most recent paper that I know of is [6]), and we are pretty close
>   to having a purely categorical proof of the strong normalisation theorem
>   for lambda calculi that, unlike the syntactic proofs, is completely
>   generic with regard to the calculus in question.
>
> Freyd originally showed that the terminal object (1) of the free topos (F) is projective, and more generally the "global sections functor" 
>   F(1,-) : F -> S preserves colimits.   In particular, it preserves the
>   initial object (0), which is categorical jargon for saying that S proves
>   the consistency of F, because the S-set of F-morphisms 1->0 is the
>   initial (empty) S-set.
>
> I found this suspicious, because the punch-line of Andre Joyal's 1973
>   (but as yet unpublished and unavailable) categorical proof of Godel's
>   incompleteness theorem is that such a functor F(1,-) : F -> S does *not*
>   preserve the initial object.
>
> The more careful amongst categorists ought also to be suspicious when
>   I speak of "a functor F(1,-) or [] : F -> S" where F is an INTERNAL 
>   category in S.   The meaning that we must give to this phrase is that
>   it is "syntactic sugar" for a certain FIBRATION  p: V -> F, where V is
>   also an internal category and p and internal functor in S.
>
> This brings us back to the relationship between Replacement as a recursive construction of objects and Replacement as infinitary colimits:
>   "p: V -> F"  is the colimit (in a 2-category whose objects are fibrations)
>   of a recursively defined diagram vaguely similar to that which gives Scott's D-infinity.
>
> I have come to the conclusion that attempts to define "colimits" such as
>   this are inherently circular: what, after all, does it mean to have a
>   "cocone" to test such an alleged colimit?
>
> My categorical formulation of Replacement speaks about fibrations
>   and smaller colimits defined internally in the style of Benabou.
>   This is to be found in the final section (9.5) of my book [7],
>   Section 7.7 of which also gives an account of Freyd's gluing construction.
>
> This book is officially due to be published in mid-May,  but it is
>   already in stock (and I have my own copy in front of me), and is
>   available direct from the publishers at 50 pounds (inclusive of overland
>   postage and packing).   Please contact
>       Richard Knott,
>       email:  rknott@cup.cam.ac.uk
>       fax:    +44 1223 315 052
>       tel:    +44 1223 325 916 (but other methods are preferable)
>       snail:  Cambridge University Press, The Edinburgh Building,
>                   Shaftesbury Road, Cambridge, CB2 2RU, UK
>   with your address and credit card number.  (2.50 pounds extra for airmail.)
>
> Having seen that Replacement provides a UNIFORM way of proving
>   consistency of any fragment of logic, we come at last to the
>   inconsistency argument:
>
> Let L(0) be Zermelo set theory
>       (or the axioms for an elementary topos).
>
> For each n,  let L(n+1)  be   L(n)  plus
>       as much of the axiom-scheme of replacement as is needed
>       to justify the gluing construction that shows that
>
> ```
>   L(n+1) |-  ``L(n) is consistent.''
> ```
>
> Now let   L(infinity)   be   the union of  L(n) over n:N.
>
> If    L(infinity) |- false   then   L(n) |- false   for some n.
>
> But   L(infinity) |-  ``L(n) is consistent,''
>
> so    L(infinity)   proves its OWN consistency,
>       contradicting Godel's theorem.
>
> However,  L(infinity)   has a standard non-trivial interpretation
>       in Zermelo--Fraenkel set theory, which is therefore inconsistent.
>
> [1] Paul Taylor, Intuitionistic Sets and Ordinals, JSL 61 (1996) 705-44
>
> [2] Richard Montague, Fraenkel's Addition to the Axioms of Zermelo,
>       pp 91--114 of Bar-Hillel, et al., eds., Essays on the Foundations of 
>       Mathematics, Magnes Press, Hebrew University, 1966 (distributed
>       by Oxford University Press).
>
> [3] Adrian Mathias, The Ignorance of Bourbaki, Mathematical Intelligencer, 14 (1992) 4-13.
>
> [4] Nicolas Bourbaki, Elements de Mathematique XXII: Theories des Ensembles, Livre I, Structures, Hermann, 1957 (English translation 1968).
>
> [5] Per Martin-Lof, An Intuitionistic Theory of Types: Predicative part,
>       pp 73--118 in Rose and Sheperdson, eds., Logic Colloquium '73,
>       North-Holland, Studies in Logic and the Foundations of Mathematics #80,
>       1975
>
> [6] Djordje Cubric, Peter Dybjer and Philip Scott, Normalisation and the 
>       Yoneda Embedding, MSCS 8 (1998) 153--192.
>
> [7] Paul Taylor, Practical Foundations of Mathematics, Cambridge University Press, Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics #59, xii+572pp, 1999.
>
> http://www.dcs.qmw.ac.uk/~pt/Practical_Foundations/
>
> Paul Taylor    19990401
>
> This message may be copied elsewhere,
>   ON CONDITION that it is quoted in its ENTIRETY.

(I did quote it in its ENTIRETY, including all the headers at the top!)

(Quite a few got the joke, but I think also quite a few missed it and took Paul at his word.)

Comment: I don't get it; what was the joke?

Comment: He purports to prove that ZFC is inconsistent? And succeeded in getting some people to take him at his word?

Comment: oh. This just seems like a "mere" hoax, without very much in the way of humour (to me at least). It would be better if it were more explicitly tongue-in-cheek, I think.

Comment: Oh no, of course it was a hoax. When I said 'joke', I'm referring to his joking around, i.e., not being serious.

Comment: I had found the argument a year earlier, unfortunately several days into April, and seriously believed it for a few days. It came from trying to understand how the gluing construction managed to prove lots of consistency-like results, whilst Gödel's theorem (and in particular Joyal's categorical version of this) apparently says otherwise. I still don't understand this and believe there's a PhD thesis in doing so. Certainly it made me very suspicious of the axiom of replacement.

Answer (score 16):

This list is missing one of the greatest mathematics April Fools, the [Mandelbrot Monk article by Girvan](http://users.math.yale.edu/public_html/People/frame/Fractals/MandelSet/MandelMonk/MandelMonk.html) from 1999. It is beautifully done and famous enough to have its [own Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udo_of_Aachen).

Answer (score 15):

> The most recent additions to our Seeley G. Mudd Manuscript Library feature contributions from the estate of Oliver Wendell
> Holmes, Jr., which include letters and legal manuscripts of Pierre de Fermat (a lawyer by vocation).  It is in the density of Fermat's
> litigation records during the period 1660-1662 that his lost mathematical proof is finally to be found.

It  turns  out  that  Fermat's  proof  employs  what  is  now  known  as  the  Mason-Stothers  theorem  (proved  independently  by
Stothers [2] and Mason [3] in the late 20th century).  In the discovered manuscript, Fermat himself gave an elementary proof of the
Mason-Stothers theorem, but his approach resembles that presented in
An  alternate  proof  of  Mason's  theorem
by Snyder [4].  For
this reason we here omit Fermat's proof of the Mason-Stothers theorem, and only reproduce the subsequent part of his proof of his
last theorem, paraphrased in modern terminology.

[https://web.archive.org/web/20150403002852/http://www.princeton.edu/~aloo/fermat](https://web.archive.org/web/20150403002852/http://www.princeton.edu/%7Ealoo/fermat)

Answer (score 10):

This is perhaps only borderline mathematical, but the ChessBase website has historically made a fine art of the April Fool's joke, and arguably its most successful prank was also the most mathematical: A claim that [the King's Gambit had been solved](http://en.chessbase.com/post/the-chebase-april-fools-revisited).  They were careful not to claim that the opening had been mathematically solved, but that a generous cutoff for the score function had been set (i.e., if the computer thought that one side was "far enough ahead" then the assumption was made that that side really did have a win) and that the game tree was exhausted under this assumption.  It was clever enough that even after knowing that it *might* have been an April Fool's joke, I was still uncertain for a while.

Comment: That's actually not far (even in many subsidiary details) from yet another item in Martin Gardner's famous April column that already accounts for two answers here.

Comment: Is it certain that the hoax is really false? Any chance it is open now?

Comment: @joro : You mean the Chessbase hoax?  Yes, of course it is false.  Did you follow the link?  What do you mean "Any chance it is open now?"?  Does "it" refer to the hoax?  If so, what does it mean for a hoax to be "open"?

Comment: I read most of the link and realize it claims unproved result. The question is "Is the result false?" as in the hoax for counterexample of FLT.

Comment: @joro : I still don't fully understand, but perhaps the following remarks may help. Given any computer technology in the foreseeable future, only a tiny fraction of chess positions have the property that their value (i.e., win/loss/draw) can be established rigorously, and only a slightly less tiny fraction of chess positions can be be analyzed "semi-rigorously" in the sense of the hoax article. No "interesting" opening position such as the King's Gambit falls into either category. Note that many positions whose outcome is "morally certain" still cannot be analyzed even semi-rigorously.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I asked and suspected. Upvoted, but like the hoaxes here which are provably false better.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a counterexample to Fermat's Last Theorem, which is correct according to double precision calculations:

[image: Counterexample]

Comment: This is funny, but what is the relation with April first?

Comment: @joro: Perhaps the corresponding episode was aired on an April 1. BTW, the number in the LHS of the purported equality is (obviously) divisible by 9, whereas the number in the RHS of it is congruent to 1 modulo 9, Q.E.A.

Comment: Double precision (the usual 64-bit binary floating point of IEEE 754) has enough precision to show immediately that this is wrong. With single precision, each of the twelfth powers are rounded to positive infinity (which would not convince anyone the identity was correct). Some calculators, however, might claim this relation is correct, $3987^{12}+4365^{12}=4472^{12}$.

Comment: @J.H.S. - Unfortunately, the episode, [The Wizard of Evergreen Terrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wizard_of_Evergreen_Terrace) was aired on September 20, 1998. Damn Shame. Also, from [Fermat's Last Theorem in fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem_in_fiction): `These agree to 10 of 44 decimal digits, but notice that simple divisibility rules show 3987 and 4365 are multiples of 3 so that a sum of their powers is also. The same rule reveals that 4472 is not divisible by 3, so that this "equation" cannot hold either.`

Comment: Observe that the doughnut is undergoing a "Homertopy".

Comment: Anybody can tell what's the top line is about?

Comment: @Michael Sorry for the very belated comment, but I think it's meant to be a calculation of the Higgs mass $M(H^0)$ from simple constants. 1/137 is approximately the fine structure constant, and $\sqrt{hc/G}$ is $\sqrt{2\pi}$ times the Planck mass. This works out to about 775 GeV, which is well above the (now measured) Higgs mass, about 125 GeV.

Answer (score 10):

The following is output from Maple:

```
A := 34816783:  
B := 29698715047:  
C := 120979604904878607889:  
D := 103195600023374741883001:

isprime (A);   true    
isprime (B);   true    
isprime (C);   true  
isprime (D);   true 

AxD;  3592938812568633315821457205783  
BxC;  3592938812568633315821457205783  
AxD-BxC; 0
```

Thus AxD and BxC are two  prime factorizations of 
3592938812568633315821457205783.

This was widely distributed decades ago by a German mathematician. In the current version of Maple versions this no longer works,but a similar hoax with different numbers can probably be found.

Comment: Yet another reason not to assume unique factorization.  Gerhard "Let This Be A Warning" Paseman, 2016.04.05.

Comment: This is interesting, but is the relation with April 1? Probably it will be on topic in this question:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11517/computer-algebra-errors

Answer (score 9):

I saw Doug Ravenel give a talk that began with him announcing a proof of the Riemann Hypothesis. It was beautifully done, I thought. I didn't even realize what date it was.

http://www.math.wayne.edu/~rrb/MTS/archive/1104.html

Comment: Friedlander once started a talk with "Theorem: $\zeta(s)\neq 0$ for $\Re s>1/2$". When the audience started breathing again, he turned around and said: "This is a theorem. We just do not know yet who will prove it."

Answer (score 8):

A breathless announcement of a weakness in ubiquitous cryptography based on elliptic curves:

> this result will require a major increase in parameter for elliptic curve cryptosystems ... we recommend increasing elliptic curve key sizes from 256 bits to 3072 bits

This 2016 claim seems almost plausible until one considers how sphere packing really relates to faster discrete logarithm computation.  It deserves bonus points for using recent actual papers by Viazovska et al. to construct its argument.

- Steven Galbraith, [*ECDLP can be solved in 24-th root time*](https://ellipticnews.wordpress.com/2016/03/31/ecdlp-can-be-solved-in-24-th-root-time/).  Published 1 April 2016 at ellipticnews.wordpress.com.

Comment: :-) For 256 bit prime, the complexity is about O(2^11).

Answer (score 7):

There is also [Daniel Schoch's article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.6902) in which he give way how to obtain number of Gods in our universe using Euler characteristic.

Answer (score 7):

The mathematician philosopher Hilary Putnam otherwise not known for lightheadedness revealed on april 1, 1980 that subtle logical phenomena in the context of the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem imply the impossibility of fixing an intended model of anything, including the natural numbers (!) and the reals. This actually got published the same year:

Putnam, Hilary. Models and reality. J. Symbolic Logic 45 (1980), no. 3, 464-482.

Comment: Is there online reference?

Comment: @joro, the paper is available at https://www.princeton.edu/~hhalvors/teaching/phi520_f2012/putnam1980.pdf But, katz, are you saying that something intended as an April Fools joke got published as a serious paper, with no disclaimer, in the Journal of Symbolic Logic?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, this is for april fools' jokes, no?

Comment: It's for reporting on them, not for making them (and, anyway, the canonical day for making them has come and gone).

Comment: @Gerry, sorry. In my defense I could add that I am less than my usual two weeks late with this assignment (also the question was closed for a while).

Answer (score 5):

https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.13758, "A non-Euclidean story or: how to persist when your geometry doesn’t", by $\mathbb{R}$ami Luisto.

> Too little mathematics has been written in prose. Thus we prove here, via a fantasy novellette, that a locally $L$-bilipschitz mapping $f:X \to Y$ between uniformly Ahlfors $q$-regular, complete and locally compact path-metric spaces $X$ and $Y$ is an $L$-bilipschitz map when $Y$ is simply connected. The motivation for such a result arises from studying the asymptotic values of BLD-mappings with an empty branch set; see e.g. [L17].

A small selection:

> Urist had been recently promoted to the position of the royal mapmaker... Urist's task is far from easy. Ever since their clash with the local necromancer a century ago, the standard three dimensions no longer limit the geometry of the world as a terrible curse shattered the shape of space. The extent of the distortion is so far unknown... Not that the concept of "dimension" makes much easy sense anymore; it took the scholars years to figure out that while the concept of "direction" was no longer present, distances and volumes still exist and the volume of any given ball of radius $r$ seemed to be equal to $r^q$, up to some global multiplicative constants at least. The technical term for this is that *the fortress $(X,d,\mu)$ is a uniformly locally Ahlfors $q$-regular metric measure space, i.e. there exists constants $C \geq 1$ and $r_0 > 0$ such that*
>   $$ C^{−1} r^q \leq  \mu (B(x, r)) \leq C r^q $$
>   *for all $x \in X$, $0 < r < r_0$.* This fact had immediate applications to the crucial brewing and storing industries, and the scholars were heralded as the saviors of ale and thus of dwarves.

Comment: Is it an April Fools' joke? or is it just a strange way to write a real paper? Luisto has published several papers on BLD mappings.

Comment: It's a paper with a real result. I didn't quote the whole abstract; part of what I left out is "As far as the author is aware, the result is new, even though it would not be hard for specialists in the field to prove." So, no, it's not a hoax (as far as I know) or *purely* a joke. However the paper appeared on April 1 and clearly has a humorous intent in the writing style.

Comment: Now also finally published! https://scholarship.claremont.edu/jhm/vol12/iss1/41/

"Is it an April Fools' joke? or is it just a strange way to write a real paper?" It can be both ^^

Answer (score 5):

[A genuinely natural information measure](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.16662) [arXiv:2103.16662]

> The theoretical measuring of information was famously initiated by
> Shannon in his mathematical theory of communication, in which he
> proposed a now widely used quantity, the entropy, measured in bits.
> Yet, in the same paper, Shannon also chose to measure the information
> in continuous systems in nats, which differ from bits by the use of
> the natural rather than the binary logarithm.      We point out that
> there is nothing natural about the choice of logarithm basis, rather
> it is arbitrary. We remedy this problematic state of affairs by
> proposing a genuinely natural measure of information, which we dub
> gnats. We show that gnats have many advantages in information theory,
> and propose to adopt the underlying methodology throughout science,
> arts and everyday life.

Answer (score 4):

[I think this short note by D. Zeilberger counts,](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.1532.pdf) I am not sure though if it was intended for an April 1st joke.

Note: Zeilberger's conjecture is equivalent with the Collatz conjecture.

Answer (score 3):

There is an "April Fools" issue of the Math Horizons, published in 2007:

http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/horizonsarchive/Horizons-Apr07lores.pdf

Answer (score 2):

https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.00108

A Farewell to Falsifiability
Douglas Scott, Ali Frolop, Ali Narimani, Andrei Frolov
(Submitted on 1 Apr 2015)

Some of the most obviously correct physical theories - namely string theory and the multiverse - make no testable predictions, leading many to question whether we should accept something as scientific even if it makes no testable predictions and hence is not refutable. However, some far-thinking physicists have proposed instead that we should give up on the notion of Falsifiability itself. We endorse this suggestion but think it does not go nearly far enough. We believe that we should also dispense with other outdated ideas, such as Fidelity, Frugality, Factuality and other "F" words. And we quote a lot of famous people to support this view.