# Limit/Expansion Problems for Benchmarking

Tags: limits-and-convergence, computer-algebra

I am interested in collections of ‘interesting’ problems involving limits and/or asymptotic expansions of univariate real-valued functions. The purpose is to test a particular algorithm that I implemented in a theorem prover. Problems that are typically considered ‘difficult’ for computer algebra systems would be particularly interesting.

[Dominik Gruntz's thesis](http://www.cybertester.com/data/gruntz.pdf) contains a few problems like that, but I'd like to have more. Is there a collection like this? Perhaps something in the context of a particular computer algebra system, e.g. for regression tests?

Comment: You might find something you can use in this compilation of computer algebra errors: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11517/computer-algebra-errors

Comment: *"of real-valued functions"* of one variable or of several variables?

Comment: Univariate. You're right, I should, of course, have mentioned that.